# Setting ComboBox ItemSource/SelectedValue in custom control

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, binding

How can I duplicate the following code in code (not XAML)?

```
<ComboBox Name="DisplayValueComboBox" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={wpfUtil:EnumBindingSource {x:Type unitTypes:FeetOrMetersSelectionType}}}" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=DisplayValueType}"></ComboBox>
```

I'm attempting to create a custom user control that is generic.  To do this, I have to do it in all code.  My custom control is simply a text box and a combo box.  The combo box should contain items within the enum (specified in generic).  The items will be the list of units to display (feet/meters, degrees/radians, etc.).  If the user changes the units, the value in the text box will be converted (using the MultiValueConverter)  I've done the combo enum binding through XAML with the method described [here](http://brianlagunas.com/a-better-way-to-data-bind-enums-in-wpf/).  And, I've got the control working without the generic for a Feet/meters unit control.  But, now I'm lost as to how to set the ItemSource and SelectedValue within the constructor of the generic.

Below is the rest of the base generic and the child class if it helps:

```
/// <summary>
/// Control that displays value in different units depending on selected unit type.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TDisplayTypeEnum">The enumeration type for all the available units.</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TConverterType">The MultiValueConverter that converts the value between the different types of units.</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TValueType">The underlying type of the stored value.</typeparam>
public class UnitControlBase<TDisplayTypeEnum, TConverterType, TValueType> : UserControl
    where TDisplayTypeEnum : struct, IConvertible
    where TConverterType : IMultiValueConverter, new()
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor.
    /// </summary>
    public UnitControlBase()
    {
        Grid mainGrid = new Grid();
        mainGrid.Name = "LayoutRoot";
        this.AddChild(mainGrid);

        ColumnDefinition col1 = new ColumnDefinition();
        ColumnDefinition col2 = new ColumnDefinition();
        mainGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col1);
        mainGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col2);

        TextBox displayValueTextBox = new TextBox();
        displayValueTextBox.Name = "DisplayValueTextBox";
        MultiBinding mb = new MultiBinding();
        mb.Converter = new TConverterType();
        mb.Bindings.Add(new Binding("Value"));
        mb.Bindings.Add(new Binding("ValueType"));
        mb.Bindings.Add(new Binding("DisplayValueType"));
        displayValueTextBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, mb);
        Grid.SetColumn(displayValueTextBox, 0);
        mainGrid.Children.Add(displayValueTextBox);

        ComboBox displayValueComboBox = new ComboBox();
        displayValueComboBox.Name = "DisplayValueComboBox";            
        //displayValueComboBox.ItemsSource = ???
        //displayValueComboBox.SelectedValue = ???
        Grid.SetColumn(displayValueComboBox, 1);
        mainGrid.Children.Add(displayValueComboBox);            
    }

    private static FrameworkPropertyMetadata valuePropertyMetadata = new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(TValueType));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(TValueType), typeof(UnitControlBase<TDisplayTypeEnum, TConverterType, TValueType>), valuePropertyMetadata);

    public TValueType Value
    {
        get
        {
            return (TValueType)GetValue(ValueProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
        }
    }

    private static FrameworkPropertyMetadata valueTypePropertyMetadata = new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(TDisplayTypeEnum));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueTypeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ValueType", typeof(TDisplayTypeEnum), typeof(UnitControlBase<TDisplayTypeEnum, TConverterType, TValueType>), valueTypePropertyMetadata);

    public TDisplayTypeEnum ValueType
    {
        get
        {
            return (TDisplayTypeEnum)GetValue(ValueTypeProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
        }
    }

    private static FrameworkPropertyMetadata displayValueTypePropertyMetadata = new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(TDisplayTypeEnum));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayValueTypeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("DisplayValueType", typeof(TDisplayTypeEnum), typeof(UnitControlBase<TDisplayTypeEnum, TConverterType, TValueType>), displayValueTypePropertyMetadata);

    public TDisplayTypeEnum DisplayValueType
    {
        get
        {
            return (TDisplayTypeEnum)GetValue(DisplayValueTypeProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(DisplayValueTypeProperty, value);
        }
    }   
}
```

Child class:

```
public class FeetMetersControlBase : UnitControlBase<FeetOrMetersSelectionType, FeetToMetersMultiValueConverter, double>
{
}
```

Feet/Meters Type:

```
public enum FeetOrMetersSelectionType
{
    Feet,
    Meters
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
displayValueComboBox.ItemsSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(TDisplayTypeEnum));
displayValueComboBox.SetBinding(ComboBox.SelectedItemProperty, new Binding("DisplayValueType") { Source = this });
```

Comment: That worked.  It didn't even come to me to get the enum values directly.  I was trying to use the stuff that I had to create for the XAML.